# JSF do not interpret placeholder in <h:outputText value="#{tableRow.x}" />

Tags: java, spring, jsf, richfaces

I am mixing jsf,richfaces and spring together (faces backing beans = spring beans) and I have a jsp page with a table. For some strange reason tag

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{inputBean.table}" var="tableRow">
```

calls inputBean.getTable() method and construct output table with the same amount table rows which table(List) has -> #{inputBean.table} was replaced with an object table from inputBean.

But when I want to display a row X value by

```
<h:outputText value="#{tableRow.x}" />
```

only `#{tableRow.x}` is displayed on a page, not the value. I think that it could be some configuration problem that richfaces are configured right but jsf not(h:outputText is jsf tag)

Any ideas? I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.
Page:

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>
<html>
 <body>
 <f:view>
 <h:form>
    <rich:dataTable value="#{inputBean.table}" var="tableRow">
  <f:facet name="caption">
   <h:outputText value="United States Capitals" />
   </f:facet>
   <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Capitals and States Table" />
   </f:facet>
   <rich:column>
    <f:facet name="header">x</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{tableRow.x}" />
    <f:facet name="footer">State Name</f:facet>
   </rich:column>
   <rich:column>
    <f:facet name="header">lx</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{tableRow.lx}" />
   <f:facet name="footer">State Capital</f:facet>
   </rich:column>
           <f:facet name="footer">
    <h:outputText value="Capitals and States Table" />
          </f:facet>
  </rich:dataTable>
 </h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
 <!--  *********** Faces config *********** -->
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>server</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <!-- Faces Servlet -->
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <!-- Faces Servlet Mapping -->
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <!--  *********** Faces config *********** -->
 <!--  *********** rich faces config *********** -->
 <!-- Plugging the "Blue Sky" skin into the project -->
 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
  <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <!-- Making the RichFaces skin spread to standard HTML controls -->
 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
  <param-value>enable</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <!-- Defining and mapping the RichFaces filter -->
 <filter>
  <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
  <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>
 <!--  *********** rich faces config *********** -->
 <!--  *********** Spring config *********** -->
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <!--  *********** Spring config *********** -->
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>
      index.jsp
    </welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

application config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
  <!-- the parent application context definition for the springapp application -->
    <bean id="inputBean" class="backingbeans.InputBean"  scope="request">
         <property name="tableService" ref="tableService"/>
    </bean>    
    <bean id="tableService" class="TableServiceImpl"  scope="session">        
    </bean>
  </beans>
```

Comment: To exclude one and other, add `<h:outputText value="#{inputBean.table}" />` *before* the `<rich:dataTable>` and let us know what it displays.

Comment: What is class of object in tableRow? Does it have method getX()?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I already tried just simple code only with h:outputText, no rich tags - same result. 
TableRow has getX() method. It does not work in other beans as well. Log says nothing wrong:-( My opinion is that the h-tag is not fully interpreted with jsf-> it seems to be configuration or library problem.I think it must be somewhere when jsf generates the code, it replaces the tag but not the value.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after one day spent by configuring I found the error - I was using richfaces 3.1.0 but jsf 1.2 !!! After I migrated to jsf 2.x problems disappeared suddenly. I think that main problem was that new richfaces can not be mixed with old jsf.